# Алгоритм нахождения нужного маршрута

Tags: алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание:

> Проложите такие маршруты от основания до вершины числовой пирамиды, чтобы суммы чисел, которые будут на каждом из них, равны соответственно 35, 45, 55.

Как я понимаю эту пирамиду нужно реализовать в форме двоичного дерева, отсортировать его, а после выбрать нужную ветку ?

Comment: Что-то навскидку ничего, кроме перебора 2^6=64 вариантов, не придумывается... Дерево в этом случае не надо: просто выбор левого пути, скажем, 0, правого - 1, вот и все...

Comment: @Harry _пирамиду нужно реализовать в форме двоичного дерева_ - не вижу запретов на движение "вбок", и даже на самопересечение. Так что не 2^6, а немножко больше. Ну и в дополнение - от вершины к основанию строить проще.

Comment: @Akina по поводу реализации в формате дерева - это всего лишь мое предположение, а не условие задания.

Comment: Двоичное дерево тут наверное не подойдет. Поскольку иного не оговорено, то в 7 на уровне 4 (сверху, считая вершину уровнем  1) можно попасть как из 9, так и из 4 с уровня 3 (это если просматривать путь в обратном направлении). Наверное тут лучше представить данные в виде матрицы (левый нижний треугольник) и идти от вершины вниз - вправо - влево (накапливая пути в очереди), пока не достигнете основания с нужным результатом. Понятно, что перебор (и очевидный недобор) можно сразу отбрасывать.

Comment: @Akina Почему - *нужно*? Тем более что в вашем варианте дерево точно не получится. А что до разрешенных путей - то как обычно: нет внятного ТЗ - получаем ХЗ... Что до "от вершины" - так именно это я и рассматривал, говоря о 0 и 1...

Comment: @Hardc0re Будьте добры, уточните разрешенные перемещения...

Comment: @Harry Прошу простить, первый коммент был предназначен ТС. Отвлёкся я чуть больше, чем надо, и влепил не то имя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте любой стандартный алгоритм поиска пути. Я бы использовал полный перебор и простую рекурсию. Условие окончания - текущая сумма не меньше заданной, критерий вывода - равенство текущей суммы заданной плюс текущее местоположение - основание. Схематично:

```
proc findpath(currentway, currentplace, currentsum)
if currentsum >= checksum then
    if currentplace.level=0 and currentsum=checksum then
        output currentway
    end if
else
    for i=0 to 5
        call findpath(currentway+currentplace, currentplace.moveto(i), currentsum+currentplace.weight)
    next i
end if
end proc
```

Comment: Для удобства (и упрощения) работы алгоритма пирамидальную схему надо трансформировать в треугольную матрицу с "обрамляющим контуром" (т.е. вершина имеет индекс 2,2), а "несуществующим элементам" присвоить значение не менее заданной суммы. Тогда при выходе за границу сразу наступит превышение текущей суммы и останов рекурсии без вывода текущего пути.